# Changing turf.js buffered polygon corners to sharp corners in Leaflet?

Tags: polygon, leaflet, buffer, turf

I'm using `Turf JS` to make a polygon bigger with 10 meters:

```
var buffered = turf.buffer(polyGeoJSON, 10, { units: 'meters' });
```

and after, I'm adding it to the map

```
var outerBuff = L.geoJSON(buffered , {
    weight: 0,
    lineJoin: "miter",
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    fillColor: "red"
});
map.addLayer(outerBuff);
```

But it seems that it makes the corners round, and `miter` doesn't seem to change their shape.
This is how it looks [image: picture1]
It is possible to make the corners sharp? Like: [image: this]

Comment: @TomazicM Added two pictures. The shape shouldn't have rounded corners, but "regular" ones, as you usually draw a rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve sharp corners with the `turf.buffer` function. By buffer definition shortest distance of every point of buffered polygon should be equal to `radius` parameter of the function.

If you just look at the image of polygon that is buffered the way you want, you'll see that at the sharp corners distance is much higher, and that's why buffered polygon is round at the corners. Here is image of all three cases:

[image]

To get enlarged polygon with sharp edges you have to use `turf.transformScale(geojson, factor)` function (see https://turfjs.org/docs/#transformScale). Here you don't have absolute `radius` parameter, but relative `scale` parameter, so if you have some fixed value for your enlargement, you will have to adjust `scale` parameter according to the size (bounding box) of the polygon.